# Fill a SharePoint List with a list<splistitem>

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

I'm working in a webpart. I filter (with caml) a SharePoint list and put my results in a `List<SPListItem>`.

Now, i need to populate another SharePoint List (I created that list in the same code) and i can't find the way to do that.

```
List<SPListItem> results = new List<SPListItem>()  //results have the result of my    query
.
.
.
SPList listFiltered = mySite.Lists[newListName];      //listFiltered is my newlist
SPListItemCollection newListItems = listFiltered.Items; //newListItem are the item from my list
foreach (SPListItem item in results)
{
      //I don't know how to send my result to my SharePoint list :(
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define your other List, then you can add a new SPListItem to that list with the columns that list contains. I am not sure what `results` is, if that is a typo or not, but I included that in my answer. You would need to change that if `results` does not exist.

```
SPList secondList = web.Lists["MyList"];
foreach(SPListItem item in results)
{
     SPListItem Item = secondList.Items.Add();
     item["Title"] = companyName
     item["DateReceived"] = System.DateTime.Now;
     item["Description"] = companyDesc;
     item.Update();
}
```